# *Updated further down*VBA: Replace column of cells and their adjacent cells with VLookup values

Tags: vba, excel

So below is my current code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Name_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindWhat As String, ReplaceWith As String
Dim dataCells As Range
Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "^[0-9]+[-A-Z]*[-0-9]+$"

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

FindWhat = Worksheets("Add").Range("B4")
If FindWhat = "False" Then Exit Sub  ' Replacing this with regex matching later

ReplaceWith = Worksheets("Add").Range("D4")
If ReplaceWith = "False" Then Exit Sub  ' Replacing this with regex matching later

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = Worksheets("Add").Name Then Exit For
    ws.Cells.Replace What:=FindWhat, Replacement:=ReplaceWith, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation, "Update"

End Sub

Sub VLTEST()
Worksheets("Add").Range("B6") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Tom", Worksheets("Test Table").Range("C4:D7"), 2, True)
End Sub
```

What I am looking to do is when I replace a value in a sheet I also replace the cell to it's right with a VLookup in another table.

SO the sheet(called "Data") where I want to replace values is like this:

```
  A        B
-------------------
Timmy   Is cool 
Andy    Is ok   
Paul    Is enemy No.1   
Timmy   Is cool 
Andy    Is ok   
Paul    Is enemy No.1   
Timmy   Is cool 
Andy    Is ok   
Paul    Is enemy No.1   
Timmy   Is cool 
Andy    Is ok   
Paul    Is enemy No.1
```

And my second sheet(called "Test Table") has the following table

```
Name    Att.
-------------------
Timmy   Is cool
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1 
Greg    Goes here
```

And my other sheet(called "Add") has a form that looks like this:

```
Old Code        New Code
------------------------
Timmy           Greg         BUTTON
```

When user presses the button it replaces the value "Timmy" with "Greg" in the first sheet giving you:

```
  A        B
-------------------
Greg    Is cool
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1 
Greg    Is cool
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1 
Greg    Is cool
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1 
Greg    Is cool
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1
```

But what I would like to do is figure out how to reference the adjacent cell to those being replaced and implement my VLTest function to basically VLookup "Greg"s Att. in the table on the "Test Table" sheet and end up with:

```
  A        B
-------------------
Greg    Goes here
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1 
Greg    Goes here
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1
Greg    Goes here
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1
Greg    Goes here
Andy    Is ok
Paul    Is enemy No.1
```

I feel like I'm not getting anywhere with this. Can anyone help?

> Update: Mrigs answer works

Mrigs answer works for me and I'm glad to have it, but I have only one more problem now

With Test Table as:

[image]

I've changed:

```
cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Goes Here"    'replace adjacent value
```

To:

```
cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(testWS.Range("B1").Value, Worksheets("Test Table").Range("A1:B5"), 2, True)    'replace adjacent value
```

But it doesn't seem to look up the correct value

e.g

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Timmy", Worksheets("Test Table").Range("A1:B5"), 2, True)
```

Returns: "Goes here" -- should be "is cool"

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Greg", Worksheets("Test Table").Range("A1:B5"), 2, True)
```

Returns: "is hot" -- should be "Goes here"

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Phil", Worksheets("Test Table").Range("A1:B5"), 2, True)
```

Returns: "is yes no" -- correct

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Andy", Worksheets("Test Table").Range("A1:B5"), 2, True)
```

Returns: "is hot" --correct

Why are the first and last rows returning the wrong ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming sheet `Data` is as follows

[image]

and sheet `Test Table` is

[image]

Following might help

```
Sub Worksheet_Name_Change()
    Dim dataWS As Worksheet, testWS As Worksheet
    Dim srcRng As Range, cel As Range
     
    Set dataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set testWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test Table")
    
    With dataWS
        Set srcRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, 1))    'set range in column A
    End With
    
    For Each cel In srcRng    'loop through each cell in Column A
        If cel.Value = testWS.Range("A2").Value Then    'check is value is to be replaced
            cel.Value = testWS.Range("B2").Value    'replace the value
            cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Goes here"    'replace adjacent value
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

I am assuming you want to display `Goes here` beside the replaced value.

Output will be

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Trying it now. However I'm going to try to implement "Test Table" as the table I want to lookup the value